# Every draw style

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I frequently use `every node/.style={blue,draw}` to set style for every node as in the MWE below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={blue,draw}]
    \node {Text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to apply this method to **draw** not **node**, but I failed to it.
Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every draw/.style={->,red,thick}]
    \draw(0,0)--(5,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no `every draw` available. One possible way is to style `every path`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={->,red,thick}]
    \draw(0,0)node[left]{$ A $}--(5,0)node[right]{$ B $};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative solution is to globally set `draw` for `every picture`. In this way, color specification does not affect node!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={->,draw=red,thick}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw(0,0)node[left]{$ A $}--(5,0)node[right]{$ B $};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will also affect nodes.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yep! you are right. But it seems there is no easy way to style only `draw`.

Comment: I don't know of any, but there might be a way. A workaround would be to place all the `\draw`s in a `scope` environment and add the `every path` style to the `scope` options.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have said, you can set `every path`, but that changes the node styles.  One way around this is to set `every node` just afterwards:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={->,red,thick},
  every node/.style={draw,blue,thin}]
  \draw(0,0)--(5,0) node[rectangle] {XX} -- (5,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={midway, sloped, font=\tiny},
decoration={show path construction,
lineto code={
\draw [red, thick,->] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);},}]
\path [decorate] (0,0) -- (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You cant  use node since you set "draw style". I suggest to use tikzlibrary decorations.pathreplacing to set the decoration "path construction". More info see in tikz-pgf manual by T. Tantau

Comment: I got the idea now! Thank you for your pointing out. Actually, I misunderstood about key-val in tikz-pgf. I can just change `every draw/.style={->,red,thick}` to `every path/.style={->,red,thick}`

Comment: Ok, if you dont mind, show your solution here. Will be helpful for people)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comment above, here is a demo using `every path` in a scope environment to achieve a style effect on a group of paths, including nodes. Note the draw operations before and after the scope get default styling.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) rectangle ++(4,4);

\begin{scope}[every path/.style={draw, line width=2.0mm, color=red}]
    \draw (1,1) -- ++(4,0);
    \draw (2,2) rectangle ++(3,3);
    \node at (3,3) {Narf};
\end{scope}

\draw (3,3) -- ++(4,0);
\node[draw] at (6,6) {Poit};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To apply this technique and have the style apply to `draw` but not `node`,  put all `draw` commands within the scope and keep all `node` commands outside the scope.

[image: scope example]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  As this is still styling the nodes, I don't see how this helps the OP.

Comment: @AndrewSwann The point is to be able to write your style info once using `every path`, instead of having to re-write it for every path/node. But by organizing the code using `scope`, you can also keep some paths/nodes with your default style. In other words, this *doesn't* style any nodes that are outside the scope.

Comment: I'm sure it's a very simple example if you've been using `tikz` for any length of time, but this is all quite new to me.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I have added a `\node` to the example, specifically outside the scope, to show that not all nodes get the style using this technique.

Comment: I agree with you that scoping is useful, but it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Perhaps this helps clarify, I will add it as an edit: to apply the style to draw but not node, put all draw commands within the scope. Keep all node commands outside the scope.  This is an improvement in functionality over the currently accepted answer.