# Trying to draw a line using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I would like a simple plot that shows a line with a negative slope. I do not want to show a specific line. I am using the package pgfplots. Here is what I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
    xlabel = \(x\),
        ylabel = {\(mx+b\)},
        ]
    \addplot [
    domain=-3:10, 
        samples=25, 
]
{-3*x + 4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It would be what I want except it is a plot of a specific line. I would like to fix the problem by telling LaTeX not to generate the hash marks on the x-axis and the y-axis when it produces the graph. How do I do that?

Comment: why make tex work to plot this rather than simply drawing a line?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well I could not find a function to draw a line. I suspect it is there and I am missing it.

Comment: look at tikz not pgfplots, you are drawing 26 line segments to approximate a line, which is somewhat over engineered

Comment: like this but with coordinates that are not the same y coordinate https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302931/1090

Comment: You can also just use coordinates, if you want to stick to using a plot: `\addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(-3,13) (10,-26)};`. Which marks exactly don't you want to show? Maybe try adding `ticks = none` as option to the `axis` environment.

Comment: If you want to stick to your version with plotting a function, then you should at least decrease the sample size to increase compilation speed. It is sufficient to set `samples=2` for this.

Comment: @Bob, please make sure, code you post does compile when copied. This unfortunately doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to make it look like a generic negative linear line:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines = center,
  axis line style={->},
  xtick=\empty, xlabel = \(x\),
  ytick=\empty, ylabel = {\(mx+b\)},
]
\addplot [domain=-3:10, samples=2] {-3*x + 4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this code should produce a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

It looks rather better (in my opinion) with `axis lines = center`, but you can try it with `axis lines = left` if you prefer.

The `xtick=\empty` setting is documented on p.336 of the vast PGFPlots manual.